# Segmentation Fault data not showing in GDB

Tags: c++, gdb, g++

I am using the g++ compiler to compile my code, and I am reaching a Segmentation Fault after the main method returns. I am unable to get what is causing the fault as GDB returns each frame on the stack in the form: #0  0x00007ffff7007478 in ?? ().

The frame #5 is 0x0000000000000000 in ?? () and I find it interesting that it's at address 0, does that mean anything in particular?

I have updated GDB and my g++ compile flags are: -std=c++11 -g -ggdb -O0

Any ideas? If you need anything more, let me know. Thanks!

Comment: It means that your code has a bug. Without a [mcve], no further answer is possible.

Comment: Many times a 0x0 stack frame indicates a stack overwrite or a call to null function pointer

Comment: `-ggdb` implies `-g`. You may want to consider compiling with `-fsanitize=address` or running the program under valgrind.

Answer (score 0):

`0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()` is likely caused from dereferencing a null pointer.
You have the correct debugging flags enabled, but you aren't looking at the call stack.

Try running the program again through `gdb`, allow it to crash, and then run `bt`.
This will give you a back trace.  You will be able to find the last described function where the problem was likely to have occurred.